# Rendering didn't create an MP4 file, file without any extension created instead

Tags: rendering

I set my output to the same Blender file as the scene.  The entire render took place (10hr) but when I came back it was just a file symbol instead of an Mp4.  There was no video.

I'm assuming that Blender just didn't know what to do but what happened to everything that it rendered? Could it be in some other location on my PC?

I didn't have anything in the sequencer but I did still have it ticked.  I didn't know that was an option.  But if the computer took that long to render where could it have ended up?

Comment: This is one reason it is advised to render an image sequence as an intermediary step.  Not only the potential for data loss going straight to mp4 but being able to identify and replace bad frames

Comment: what do you mean by " it was just a file symbol instead of an Mp4"? Do you have a file ? if Blender didn't crash during the render, your render should have been saved into whatever file you set up. Now whether the file is readable, that depends on the software you use to read it.

Comment: OK so I rendered it as individual tiffs and again the file type of each file is just "file" they aren't tiffs

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. At some point I unchecked the File Extension tab